# Batch processing filters in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have many different labels in my Gmail account. I've set up my filters to attach labels such as `newsletters` and `social` to these emails as they come in. Once these emails are read, I want them to be archived and simply "gone" from the inbox. This is possible using the following filter, selecting all mail, then clicking archive:

```
((label:social-facebook OR label:social-twitter OR label:G+ OR label:social-spotify OR label:newsletters OR label:scanned OR label:shopping-ebay OR label:shopping-paypal) AND is:read AND label:inbox)
```

Is there is an easier way to go about this?

Comment: why don't you archive them just after you've read them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail's filters are processed immediately after the e-mail arrives in your inbox. You can not use a filter for processing an email inbox yet. What you are looking for is possible with a google script:

```
function processInbox() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var th = threads[i];
    if (!th.isUnread() && !th.isImportant() && !th.hasStarredMessages()) {
      th.moveToArchive()
    }
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Drive > new script > past the code > run and autorize > create a trigger for 4/6 hours..

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the procedure you proposed, but in steps

1. In the search box at the top of Gmail enter the following string

   label:social-twitter label:inbox is:read
2. click select all
3. Click on the link to expand to other messages on subsequent pages of you have a lot of messages
4. Click Archive
5. Go back to step one for the next label.

The advantage is that if you have dozens of labels you don't have to make a massive query statement. And that if you have do have dozens of labels you want to address you can take them a couple at a session.

Note the definition of archive in Gmail is **simply "gone" from the inbox**.

As you go forward use the archive button when you no longer need to see the message/conversation on the front page. The fact that you are using filters and labels is great, now take it to the next step by using the Archive button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Organizer by OtherInbox? It does that kind of classification and gets those emails out of your way. If it doesn't give the level of customization you need (and you have some basic ability to code) you can script those using Context.IO.

(disclaimer: I'm founder of Context.IO)